# Luigi: Is there a way to use Extended Interpolation like in configparser?

Tags: python-2.7, config, luigi

I have a luigi config file:

```
[Common]
dir: /some/path

[MyTask]
task_parameter: ${Common:dir}/other/folders/
```

But when I run luigi task with path to the config I see that `task_parameter` == `"${Common:dir}/other/folders/"`, not `"/some/path/other/folders/"`

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to use LuigiConfigParser in that way?

I use python2.7 and luigi==2.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do extended interpolation. Interpolation is Shell specific and configurations are parsed inside of Python land. Also, remember that all parameters must be serializable, so Luigi/Python would have to jump through some pretty weird hoops for this.

However, it is pretty easy to extend to what you need. What you could do is instead of specifying `task_parameter`, you could specify say `task_parameter_query` and use the string as the basis for a query when resolving the parameter's purpose. It looks like you're just trying to get an environment variable here, so you could just use `task_parameter` as a string template and then fill in the value by calling to `os.getenv`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend moving away from Python 2.* as it is now deprecated and unsupported.